# How to remove member from OptionSet

Tags: swift

I'm trying this in an iOS playground in Xcode 8 but it doesn't work:

```
struct Direction: OptionSet {
    let rawValue: UInt8
    static let none = Direction(rawValue: 0)
    static let up = Direction(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let left = Direction(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    static let down = Direction(rawValue: 1 << 2)
    static let right = Direction(rawValue: 1 << 3)
    static let all = [up, left, down, right]
}

var directions = Direction.all
directions.remove(.up)    // Error: Missing argument label 'at:' in call
```

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optionset) indicates that I should be able

> "...to add or remove members from an instance of your custom option
>   set type."

The documentation refers to a `remove()` function but this isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the declaration of `all`:

```
static let all: Direction = [.up, .left, .down, .right]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that without context, Swift will infer an array literal to be of type `[Element]` (aka `Array<Element>`). Therefore without an explicit type annotation,

```
static let all = [up, left, down, right]
```

will be inferred to be a `[Direction]`, rather than a `Direction` (which is why the compiler prompts you to use the method [`remove(at:)`](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/type/Array/#func-remove-at_)).

The solution therefore, as [@OOPer has already said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39428134/2976878), is simply to give `all` an explicit type annotation:

```
static let all : Direction = [up, left, down, right]
```

which will utilise `OptionSet`'s (rather than `Array`'s) conformance to [`ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/expressiblebyarrayliteral).

---

As a side note, an explicit `none` option is redundant, as this can be represented by an empty set:

```
let none : Direction = []
```